# Swipe views - fixed tabs

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, swipeview

I created Swipe Views with Tabs following this official Android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter to make tabs fixed and all visible. I'm developing on two PCs, on the first one the tabs are fixed, but if I run the app from the second one, they aren't. The source code, libraries and the manifest file are exactly the same.

Have anyone encountered the same problem? Howcome the tabs are not fixed even if I'm using the FragmentPagerAdapter? I dropped all my business logic, cleared workspace to avoid some configuration issues but it didn't help :-(
(the tabs definitely fit onto the screen, there are 4 of them with small icons, no titles)

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the problem. If the tabs don't fit on the screen, they are switched to be scrollable instead of fixed. One of my icons was larger than the others and I forgot to copy it from one PC to another so the difference made the tabs scrollable.